# Can anyone help me think of an app that uses a set of almost wireframe instructional elements before the user starts using the app?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

Can anyone help me think of an app that uses a set of almost wireframe instructional elements before the user starts using the app? I know I have used a few apps like that. They will show a stencil of a hand and show you how to work through the app. I am working on a UX exercise and I need some ideas on how to incorporate something like that into my project to help the user to get up and running faster in my application. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that pattern is called "coach marks" and is available in many apps. You can see it on The Weather Channel's [new weather app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-weather-channel/id295646461?mt=8) for the iPhone or iPad (shameless plug). There is also a reference on coach marks, with many examples which can be found [here](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/coach-marks).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Linda. That is exactly the info I was looking for.